# Linking Apple ID to an multiple account/user on my server

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

**Background:**

I am trying to implement In-app purchasing for my iOS app. The app allows the user to be able to log in to multiple accounts and register multiple accounts. Each registration will require the user to pay a subscription fee (unless a free plan is selected). When the registration is complete the account will be linked to the Apple ID that paid for the subscription.

**Question:**

If already have done a registration with my current Apple ID(Account A) with a $0.99 subscription every month and then do another registration with the same Apple ID(Account B) with a $1.99 subscription every month. Both accounts have purchased a subscription with the same Subscription Groups. In that case will that Apple ID just be paying for the subscription of Account B since it would be considered an upgrade from Account A.

1. I can make it so that when an account is created with an Apple ID that have been used, we link the new account with that Apple ID and disable the older one. This would however provides a bad user experience and only ever one account will work with one Apple ID and probably isn't the solution I want.

I did try to set the ApplicationUsername for SKPayment object in hopes that it will appear on the other side when the notification API is hit by Apple but it don't seem to use it for that and is used to detect fraudulent activity.

I am trying to find some documentation on handling this case but to no avail. I'm not too sure how to get around this issue and have a feeling that my app's implementation is not aligned with how Apple expects us to implement it. Maybe I have misunderstood some documentation but any insight to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The behaviour you have described under "1" is how I would expect it to work, Probably with an alert before you show the subscribe dialog that warns the user that their subscription is currently associated with Account A and that completing this step will remove Account A's subscription and associate it with Account B.

Comment: How will the app know that that particular transaction id have already been associated before completing the transaction? Maybe it can be drawn from the receipt on the local device but even then it is possible to log onto a different device with the same Apple ID the receipt will not be there locally.

Comment: When the user logs in to or creates Account B you could refresh the receipt and validate it with your server. If the subscription is already associated with another user you could give them an option to move the subscription or continue with the free level

Comment: If I do that would that mean that if the user selects free level they would have upgraded Account A(or downgraded) since the transaction already gone through?

Comment: No, you would need to check if they have a current subscription before they have submitted a purchase request.  Check when the user logs in, not when they submit a subscription request

Comment: Ahh I see that make sense. It does tho seem it is impossible to link 2 subscription to one Apple ID currently.